# jQuery Prototype function with dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery prototype that I found to catch all changes to the contents of an input (for auto fill and what not). Is there a way I can use this with dynamically created elements?

```
$.fn.allchange = function (callback) {
var me = this;
var last = "";
var infunc = function () {
    var text = $(me).val();
    if (text !== last) {
        last = text;
        callback();
    }
    setTimeout(infunc, 100);
};
setTimeout(infunc, 100);
};


// This Works, but only for fixed elements
    $(".cibp").allchange(function () {
        alert('allchange on fixed element');
    });



// Somehow get this to work
    $(document).on(allchange, '.cibp', function () {
        alert('allchange on dynamic element');
    })
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to call the allchange on the new elements as you create them.  I'm slightly curious though how having a setTimeout for every '.cibp' element on your page may affect your performance.  Also if you remove one of the elements from the page, I don't see how the logic would know it needs to stop the timeout loop

Comment: That's a fair point. There shouldn't be more than 6 or 7 elements on the page at one time, but they will be coming and going, so I would need to somehow be aware of that. Any suggestion on how I could otherwise catch a 'change' event that would include autofill?